# C split string function

Tags: c, windows, string

I am trying to implement function to split strings, but i keep getting segmentation faults. I am working on Windows XP, and therefore i also had to implement strdup(), because Windows API doesn't provide it. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the following piece of code.

```
char** strspl(char* str, char* del)
{
    int size = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str);) {
        if(strncmp(str + i, del, strlen(del)) == 0) {
            size++;
            i += strlen(del);
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    char** res = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
    res[0] = strdup(strtok(str, del));
    for(int i = 0; res[i] != NULL; i++) {
        res[i] = strdup(strtok(NULL, del));
    }
    return res;
}

char* strdup(char* str) {
    char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(str));
    strncpy(res, str, sizeof(str));
    return res;
}
```

EDIT: using a debugger i found out, that program crashes after following line:

```
res[0] = strdup(strtok(str,del));
```

Also, i fixed strdup(), but there is still no progress.

Comment: Strange, I'm sure windows has strdup.  Have you tried _strdup?

Comment: See the following link for the (short) story of `strdup` in Visual C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235454%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, strdup was deprecated.  _strdup is the one you should now be using.

Comment: Your strdup implementation is wrong. The `sizeof` operator returns the size of `char*`, not the length of str as your code seems to imply. It could be implemented as `size_t size = sizeof (*str) * (strlen (str) + 1); char *res = malloc (size); return (memcpy (res, str, size);`. As for the segfault, I haven't a clue, but your `strdup` implementation is a good start. The Windows API provides [StrDup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759969(v=vs.85).aspx) as of Windows 2000. There's also [_strdup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc(v=vs.80).aspx) as others have mentioned.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and call `strlen(del)` just once.  Also make all your arguments `const char*`.  And, `strncmp` and `strtok` act nothing alike, one treats multiple characters as a unit, the other, as a bunch of alternative single-character delimiters.

Comment: Why are you sometimes taking the delimiter to be a string (`strncmp`) and other times (sort of) a character (`strtok`)? I suggest you split at a single character, and use the signature `char **strspl(const char *src, int ch);`. Your 2nd loop is wrong: when `i` is 1 or greater you're testing uninitialized variables (`res[1]`, `res[2]`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

You're not counting the null terminator and you are copying the wrong number of bytes

```
char* strdup(char* str) {
    char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(str)); /* what about the null terminator? */
    strncpy(res, str, sizeof(str)); /* sizeof(str)
                                    ** is the same as
                                    ** sizeof (char*) */
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I see, so i should use strlen(str) instead of sizeof and allocate one more byte. Thank you very much.

Comment: To be absolutely safe, you should allocate `strlen(str) * sizeof(char) + 1` bytes.

Comment: @Adnan: I'd say it's safe to assume `sizeof(char) == 1`. In fact, C99 guarantees that. But I agree that for extreme portability, extra precaution is never a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your `strdup()` function is not correct. The `sizeof(str)` in there is the *size of the `str` pointer* (probably 4 or 8 bytes), not the *length of the string*. Use the library provided `_strdup()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` does not initialize the allocated memory to `\0`. Have you tried using `calloc` instead? I suspect the seg faults are due to the `res[i] != NULL` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with this code, but the main flaw is trying to implement this function. It will only provide you with marginal benefit, if any.

Compare the following two code snippets:

```
/* Using strtok... */
char *tok = strtok(str, del);
while (tok != NULL) {
    /* Do something with tok. */
    tok = strtok(NULL, del);
}
```

-

```
/* Using your function... */
char **res = strspl(str, del, &size);
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    /* Do something with *(res + i). */
}
```